# How to produce a USB stick from my Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I am a new Ubuntu user. 
I would like to copy my Ubuntu system with all the programs and installations that I have made into a USB.

The reason is that I cannot install Ubuntu again in all the other laptops that I have, and redo all the installations, because that would take a lot of time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A leading solution for cloning (and system backup) is **Clonezilla**.

Detailed information and download links are here: http://clonezilla.org

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on booting from the USB or just using it to copy/clone the system to the other machines?

If booting, the clone should be of the entire drive and not just a partition, The USB drive needs to be larger than the original drive.

Then if you want to clone from the USB to the laptops, their HDD's need to be larger than the USB.

If the original system contains any proprietary drivers it might not work on other machines, uninstall these before proceeding, there could also be problems with UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, or at least in an easy way. What you need to do is to preform a network install if the target laptops support this procedure, you can find that option from the boot menu by pressing F8 on most models during boot. Good luck.